# Shift all NaN values in pandas to the left

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a (250, 33866) dataframe. As you can see in the picture, all the `NaN` values are at the end of each row. I would like to shift those `NaN`values ti the left of the dataframe. At the same time I wanna keep the `0` column (which refers to the Id) in its place (stays the first one).

[image]

I was trying to define a function that loops over all rows and columns to do that, but figured it will be very inefficient for large data. Any other options? Thanks

Comment: what happens to the column names? could you mock up a toy example to show exactly what you want?

Comment: @enke the column names should stay in the same order. That is ```hour_1```, ```hour_2```, ... ```hour_33865```.

Comment: Then the values wouldn't align with the column names anymore. Is that ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reverse the columns of `df`, drop NaNs; build a DataFrame and reverse it back:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:,::-1].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(), axis=1).tolist(), 
                   columns=df.columns[::-1]).iloc[:,::-1]
```

For example, for a DataFrame that looks like below:

```
   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
1   1.0   2.0   3.0  10.0  20.0
2   1.0   2.0   3.0   NaN   NaN
3   1.0   2.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

the above code produces:

```
   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1.0   2.0   3.0  10.0  20.0
1   NaN   NaN   1.0   2.0   3.0
2   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   2.0
```

Comment: The only problem is that the ```0``` column (which is the Id) gets shifted. I want it to stay where it is

Comment: @devCharaf you could join it: `df[[0]].join(out)`

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your solution (which answers my question perfectly, thanks), when creating a dataframe with rows that have different lengths, then by the default pandas will fill empty columns (to the right) with nan, is that right?

Comment: @devCharaf yes, that’s correct

Comment: devCharaf, can you tell me why would you want your df changed in such a way that column values are changed totally. For example , in the out col14 has no NaN value where as in the original df col14 has 2 NaN. Or did you simply want the columns in the reversed direction using `df.iloc[:,::-1]`?

Comment: @ShuvashishRoy my guess is, for OP, column names don't matter but the *order* each item appears in each row is important and ending should align. One example could be time series data where observations started getting recorded at different times but ended at the same time.

Comment: thanks. Don't you think `df.iloc[:,::-1]` would have been enough in that case if col names are not important?

Comment: @ShuvashishRoy the order of the rows would be reversed. With the time series analogy, the ending would be at the beginning, which is not desired. OP's requirement: *column names should stay in the same order.*

Comment: understood, only the beginning to ending order is important for the rows. Awesome!